# Using the same form for sign-up and edit - preloading values from the database

Tags: php, pdo

I have the following function:

```
function create_table($titles, $id) { 
    $buffer = '<div id="' . $id . '">';
    foreach ($titles as $k=>$v) {
        $buffer .= '<input type="checkbox" name="' . $k . '" id="' . $k . '">';
        $buffer .= '<label for="' . $k . '">' . $v . '</label>';
    }
    $buffer .= '</div>';
    echo $buffer;
}
```

This takes the values and keys from an associative array and sets up a group of checkboxes.These are for a signup page, but I also want to use the same page for the user to edit their profile. Therefore I need a way of loading the users preferences from the database into the checkboxes 'value' property. I've thought of passing the values into the function by changing the parameters to:

```
function create_table($titles, $values, $id)
```

and then calling the function with the following parameters:

```
    $id = "reasons";
$titles = $reasons_array;
$values = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

However, if the user is trying to sign up rather than edit then the PDO Fetch will be trying to fetch from an empty database row.

If I have two different functions, one for editing one for signing up then the file will be full of `if(edit==true)` statements, but I cant think of another way of getting the values into the function IF the user is trying to edit! Help!

Comment: Add specific (boolean) value to function like `create_table($titles, $id, $register = true)` regarding value `$register` change your table you want. If you have some difference between register and edit then you HAVE TO create such argument, there is no other way (or somehow check if user is authenticated).

Comment: what, and then have the PDO::FETCH inside an `if` statement inside the create table function, so the values are only put in if the true. Is it ok to have the fetch statement inside a function?

Comment: No, all data should be prepared BEFORE view function call. Also you can check by data in array to show some menus or not. So you first prepare data then regarding it show/create your html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simple example

```
function viewTable($aData, $bEdit = false)
{
    echo $aData['some'];
    // ...
    if ($bEdit) { // or you can use isAuth() function without arg-var
        echo $aData['auth']; // hidden data only for edit page
    }
}

function getData()
{
    $aReturn['some'] = 123; // all vars you need;
    // ...
    if (isAuth()) {
        $aReturn['auth'] = 321; // only for authenticated (for edit)
    }

    return $aReturn;
}

function isAuth()
{
    return true; // check authentication
}

viewTable(getData(), isAuth());
```

Comment: ok, I like this! didnt think of functions within functions! (im still fairly new to PHP). One question - in the definition of the viewTable function you have stated `$bEdit = false`. I presume this is for a default value, and if `isAuth()` returns `true` then this default will be overwritten?

Comment: Yes `$bEdit = false` default value, yes - will be overwritten. Read any book about php, it all described there... ;)

Comment: thankyou for your help - i didnt know you could call functions as a parameter in a different function. Im going to have fun with this now!! :)

Comment: Checkout objects. Now no-one use "simple function", everybody use OOP in coding.